# Right hand rule in Faraday flux integral flat surface

Tags: electromagnetism

When calculating the flux integral $$-\iint_{\Sigma}{\frac{d\overrightarrow{B}}{dt} \cdot \overrightarrow{dA}} $$ in Faraday's law for a flat surface, which direction does $\overrightarrow{dA}$ point?

Is the rule to curl my right hand in the direction of the current then the thumb points in the direction of $\overrightarrow{dA}$? So, say the surface is in the x-y plane and we look at it from the top, the boundary goes counterclockwise, does $\overrightarrow{dA}$ point up?

Comment: $d\vec A$ is better than $\vec{dA}$, and $d\vec \Sigma$ is even better,  in case the vector potential or Poynting vector show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the surface through which you're calculating the flux is closed (in which case the canonical choice is to choose the area vector *outward*, *you* choose the direction of the area vector $\hat{A}$.  There's no rule, here; you just need to be consistent throughout the whole calculation.  You'll find that the choice doesn't affect any physical consequences.  A standard choice is to choose $\vec{A}$ so that the flux is positive.  This makes reasoning with Lenz's law easier.

Note that the right-hand rule just doesn't apply for this calculation: you're computing a dot product, not a cross-product.  Later on, you might need to use the right-hand rule to figure out the direction of the induced current, but that's not a part of the calculation of the flux.

---

To be a little more careful about this.  Faraday's Law states that a changing magnetic flux induces an emf, mathematically given by
$$
\textrm{emf} = \oint_C \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{s}=-\frac{d}{dt}\int_S\vec{B}\cdot d\vec{A} = -\frac{d\Phi_{\textrm{mag}}}{dt}\,,
$$
where the curve $C$ is the boundary of the surface $S$, oriented according to the right-hand rule. Which is to say, you choose an orientation for the surface $S$, point your thumb along this direction, and your fingers then curl in the direction along which we're integrating along $C$.

You can choose any orientation for the surface $S$ as long as you consistently choose the integration direction along $C$.

---

Now, often in practice, we compute the *absolute value* of the right-hand side of Faraday's Law to get the *magnitude* of the induced emf, and we use *Lenz's* Law to figure out the direction of the induced electric field, induced current, and/or induced magnetic field.  This separates the calculation into two pieces which makes it easier.

Comment: I know how to find out which way the current goes but what about the induced emf? Is it always negative?

Comment: @Ray What do you mean by "negative"?  emf is the line integral of the electric field: emf = $\int \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l}$. In electrostatics, this is just the the electric potential difference between the initial and final points of the path along which we're integrating.  For Faraday's Law, we know that $\oint \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l} = -\frac{d}{dt}\int_A\vec{B}\cdot d\vec{A}$. Then, the right-hand rule (used properly) tells you the direction of the *electric field* induced by the changing magnetic field, and this electric field can drive a current.

Comment: @Ray I've added a little to the post to make some of these connections clear.  The right-hand rule *does* show up directly in Faraday's Law in the sense of matching the orientation of the surface to the direction of the path along which we're integrating the induced *electric* field.